# wx dev-Cpp GDI plus problems

Tags: c++, gdi+, dev-c++

For some reason I am totally lost on this issues and been looking for an hour without any help.

in dev c++ I keep getting this error and it points to the line in [strong]bold[/strong]:

`"18 H:\Projects\Classic Lockdown\main.cpp` expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token"

```
#define INFO_BUFFER_SIZE 32767
#include "iostream"
using namespace std; 
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
//#include <GdiPlusGetEncoderClsid.h>

#include <stdio.h>
HINSTANCE G_HINS_hInstance = 0;
#include "sstream"
#include "..\PWS_DEV\PWS_DEV.h"

#pragma comment( lib, "gdiplus" )
using namespace Gdiplus;
//GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;

Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput,NULL);

Bitmap *gdiBitmap = 0;


#include "procedures.h"
```

why is it doing this?

I also wanted to see if I tried this instead

...

`Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup = "";`

...

and then I get this error instead:

`"18 H:\Projects\Classic Lockdown\main.cpp expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token"`

not matter what I used with GdiplusStartup it just keeps saying that over and over. Its like it doesn't want anything to do with GdiplusStartup

I am very stuck on this. Can some one please help me out with this?

if you need any more info about this or the project i'm working on, please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things jump out:

1. You have &m_gdiplusToken instead of &gdiplusToken (variable names don't match).
2. I assume the call to GdiplusStartup is in a function, right?

If I rearrange like this, it compiles fine with: `cl.exe /EHsc so_test.cpp`

Note I commented out headers I don't have. If it's still failing for you, you probalby have bad code in a header or you're not showing us everything.

```
#define INFO_BUFFER_SIZE 32767
#include "iostream"
using namespace std; 
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
//#include <GdiPlusGetEncoderClsid.h>

#include <stdio.h>
HINSTANCE G_HINS_hInstance = 0;
#include "sstream"
// #include "..\PWS_DEV\PWS_DEV.h"

#pragma comment( lib, "gdiplus" )
using namespace Gdiplus;


//#include "procedures.h"

int main() 
{
//GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput,NULL);
Bitmap *gdiBitmap = 0;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much jschroedl ^^. This has worked fine and it just showed me what I did wrong :D.  It will only compile if I have GdiplusStartup within a function like what you did with main or in my case under procedures. Again I thank you very much as I would of never thought of that or even find that out online.   Again thank you and you have solved this problem that I was having.